# Does The Dig (1995) take place in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars, video-games, canon, the-dig

In *[The Dig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dig)* there is that alien lobster-monster.

When discussing the evolution on the alien planet, a sentient alien says that "that one didn't evolve; it was *made*." (Or something like that. I don't remember the exact wording.)

In a post-credits scene, the lobster-monster is seen again, emitting a very familiar screech:

(At 5:27)

Is this just a typical LucasArts easter egg, or is this implying that *The Dig* actually takes place in the Star Wars universe?

Comment: You might find this interesting - "[The Dig Museum](https://web.archive.org/web/20120229031139/http://dig.mixnmojo.com/museum/dig.html)" Basically lots of interviews with the game's makers as well as reviews,

Comment: There's an original script [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20111030224650/http://dig.mixnmojo.com/downloads/The%20Dig%20-%20First%20Version.pdf) - the password is babypig

Comment: Wow, that draft is... *very* different from the final product.

Comment: The game was stuck in development hell for nearly a decade and went through 4 producers, each with their own vision.

Comment: Isn't that effect just modified Wilhelm Scream?